# How to downgrade Wsl2 to wsl1?

Tags: 20.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm using wsl 2 currently but it seems I can't run Ubuntu with it anymore.
So I want to downgrade my wsl from 2 to 1

Comment: The way you address this makes it a windows question: maintaining WSL is done from Windows tools. if you want to answer the reason for why you can not run Ubuntu find error(s) notice(s) and we can have a look at them  In theory your problem could be hardware related and installing wsl1 might not be a fix.

Answer (score 15):

The method is described on Microsoft Site: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10

How to set your wsl instance version

1. First list your distribution

   ```
   C:\WINDOWS\system32>wsl --list
   Windows Subsystem for Linux Distributions:
   Ubuntu-18.04 (Default)
   ```
2. And then set it to version 1

   ```
   C:\Users\priv>wsl --set-version Ubuntu-18.04 1
   ```

But if your problem is your rootfs, you might need to reset your instance like matigo's answer suggested.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I already reset my wsl but it didn't work for me.

Comment: Do you think it's because of my storage?my storage is full

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe you can *downgrade*, but you can completely reset WSL2 with a couple of commands:

0. Open Command Prompt
1. "Uninstall" WSL2:

   ```
   lxrun.exe /uninstall /full
   ```
2. Delete everything in `AppData\Local\lxss*`
3. Re-install WSL2:

   ```
   lxrun.exe /install
   ```

Alternatively, depending on which version of Windows you're using:

0. Open "Add/Remove Programs"
1. Find "Ubuntu" and access the advanced options
2. Choose from:

   - `repair` ⇢ attempts to fix any broken configuration files
   - `reset` ⇢ returns the installation to default (same as the process above)
   - `terminate` ⇢ kill the VM, darn the consequences
   - `uninstall` ⇢ remove WSL2 from the system